# Transform one record into more than one record using State-store(RocksDB) in Kafka Stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to transform one record into more than one record using state-store(RocksDB). I know there is one method such as stream.transform(final TransformerSupplier> transformerSupplier,final String... stateStoreNames) but how to return more than one KeyValue pair so that I can use branch later on to publish to respected topic?

There is one way to forward the data downstream but how can I use that data again?

Kafka Version - 1.1.0

Comment: I answered below, but I do not understand your second question: "how can I use that data again?". Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to emit multiple records depending on the data in your state store. With `transform()` before Kafka Streams 2.2 you can do that by calling `context.forward()` multiple times in your `Transformer`. For example:

```
stream
   .transform(() -> new Transformer<Integer, Integer, KeyValue<Integer, Integer>>() {
       private ProcessorContext context;

       @Override
       public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
           this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       public KeyValue<Integer, Integer> transform(final Integer key, final Integer value) {
           context.forward(key, value);
           context.forward(key + 1, value + 1;)
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void close() {
       }
   }, stateStoreName);
```

Note that by using `context.forward()`, you do not have compile-time type safety. If you forward records whose types do not conform to the types of the output `KStream` (`<Integer, Integer>` in the example above), the code compiles but an exception is thrown at runtime.

From Kafka Streams 2.2 onwards, you can use `flatTransform()`. With `flatTransform()` you can return a list of records instead of using `context.forward()` multiple times and return `null` as in the example above. Used in such a way `flatTransform()` guarantees compile-time type safety.

Comment: Thanks, @Bruno. It's a great help. I don't want to use stream 2.2. In the current version(1.1.0) When I  forward data to downstream then it will create a new stream? 
My second question was- how can I perform different processors on that forwarded data?

Comment: The forwarded records will be forwarded to the downstream operations in your topology. For example, if you have a `branch()` after the `transform()`, the records will be forwarded to the `branch()` and processed there.

Comment: Ok @Bruno, Now I understood. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform the record into more than one keyValue pair, you can use `flatMap` operation. You can modify the keys and values and produce zero, one or more records.

```
KStream<String, Integer> transformed = stream.flatMap(
     // Here, we generate two output records for each input record.
     // We also change the key and value types.
     // Example: (345L, "Hello") -> ("HELLO", 1000), ("hello", 9000)
    (key, value) -> {
      List<KeyValue<String, Integer>> result = new LinkedList<>();
      result.add(KeyValue.pair(value.toUpperCase(), 1000));
      result.add(KeyValue.pair(value.toLowerCase(), 9000));
      return result;
    }
  );
```

Comment: Hi Nishu, FlatMap is not applicable for stateful processor. Anyway thanks for your input.